# Global map of soil pore water salinity?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I am looking for spatially continuous data on soil salinity along coastlines. My guess is that this data does not exist, but figured I'd check here in case anyone seems to know of any. I need the data for input into a process-based model of wetland function (in which salinity may be a key component).

Comment: If any government agency has that data, it would be US Geological Survey https://data.usgs.gov/datacatalog